# I want to generate expandable list on click of button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

In my application I am having 5 checkboxes for displaying different task on another activity
in this user have to select 1, 2 or 3 checkbox which he/she want to see on next screen.
In first screen i am having Save button. after checking checkboxes user have to click on save button.
My question is I want to show only those Expandable list on second activity which is selected by user on check box when user click on save button
please tell me how to do this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

save the selected check-boxs and then when you inflate the expandable listview adapter return views only for the selected ones

Comment: But how to save the check-box? that i don't know

Comment: you case save to database/sharedpreferances/public classes etc.

Comment: Will you plz explain me in details?

Answer (score 0):

create dynamic array of selected Item, and assign this array to the group array

Comment: how can you explain in detail??

Comment: In expandable list view there is 2 list 1 one is group and second one is child so assign the selected values to group list and create child list accordingly